# How to compare Twilio 'From' numbers

Tags: python, django, twilio

I would like to compare two Twilio numbers in a database. Since they begin with "+", I'm not sure how to compare them. Here's my code to collect and save numbers to the database. I'm trying to check incoming numbers against the database.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    a = Number.objects.all()
    from_number = request.POST.get('From', None)
    u = Number(cell_number=from_number)
    u.save()
    msg_new = 'We recorded your number as %s' % (from_number)
    m = Response()
    m.message(msg_new)
    return m
```

As always, thank you for your help!

**Update**

Based on the answer I received, I updated the code. It works!

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
        from_number = request.POST.get('From', None)
        if Number.objects.filter(cell_number=from_number).exists():
            msg = "We already have your number recorded in our system."
            r = Response()
            r.message(msg)
            return r
        else:
            u = Number(cell_number=from_number)
            u.save()
            msg_new = 'We recorded your number as %s' % (from_number)
            m = Response()
            m.message(msg_new)
            return m
```

Comment: What 's `Twilio`? What do you compare something?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the Twilio numbers you are referring to are stored in the standard [E.164](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) format, which is standardised to remove all spaces etc.

If so then all you need to do is look up the number in the database. So to see if a number already exists you could do:

```
if Number.objects.filter(cell_number='+4412349834024').exists():
    # The number already exists in the database
else:
    # The number doesn't exist in the database, go ahead and add it
```

You probably want to make sure that your `cell_number` field is indexed if you will be querying it in this way.

Comment: Worked like a charm! The `exists()` is exactly what I needed.